# Wrong values on graph after zoom in Grafana

Tags: graphite, grafana

For example, graph shows me data for last 5 minutes (value = 1):

[image]

But after zoom out, for example, to "12 hours ago", it show different value (0.67):
[image]

What's happen? Is it grafana problem?

Comment: It could be that the graphite storage finder selects averaged values instead of detailed ones, based on retention settings specified in graphite conf files.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **Point consolidation**. When there is too much data points to visualise, Graphite/Grafana merges multiple points into single point which is **average** of them.

You probably want to change the consolidating function from "average" to "max" (to see the highest value from each interval).

You can change it in the function selector, by adding `consolidateBy` function. For example:

```
consolidateBy( originalFunction , 'max')
```

In Grafana doc:
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/graphite/#point-consolidation

In Graphite doc:
https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.consolidateBy